# ¿Diferencia entre Spring Boot 2.0 Snapshot y M5?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Veo que al crear un proyecto en Spring Initializr , me salen versiones de SpringBoot Snapshot y M5
¿Alguien sabe que significa?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación oficial de maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version) la versión **SNAPSHOT** es la última versión **de desarrollo** de una dependencia,

Entre los problemas que incluyen son:

- puede ser una versión inestable
- puede no parecerse en nada de un día a otro

Debemos de evitarlas como la peste, pero en algunos casos nos vemos obligados a usarlas ya que contienen una característica que no ha salido en las demás versiones o contienen algún parche de seguridad.

Ahora, como te podrás imaginar... el mayor probema con los snapshots es que...

**Tienden a desaparecer!**

Sí, si buen puedes mantener una versión de desarrollo para cada hito, lo más común es que solamente tengas una versión de desarrollo a la vez, así que cada que subes de versión, también lo hace tu snapshot y es como si desapareciera del repositorio de snapshots.

Ahora en concreto ara el caso de spring, somo dice su documentación oficial usa un [versionado semántico](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-build-gradle/wiki/Spring-project-versioning) de la siguiente manera;

```
{número}.{tipo de entrega}
```

donde el número se subdivide en

```
{mayor}.{menor}.{micro}.
```

En base a el tipo de cambio que se realice y el tipo de entrega puede ser uno de los siguientes:

- **BUILD-SNAPSHOT** Una liberación actualmente en desarrollo. estos se producen en compilaciónes automáticas diarias y se despliegan al [repositorio de snapshots](http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot).
- **M{número}** Una liberación de hito ( milestone en inglés). Normalmente se compilan manualmente, y contienen notas de liberación, se despliegan en el [repositorio de hitos](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone).
- **RC{número}** un candidato a liberación de disponibilidad general. Etos artefctos se producen de manera similar a los hitos, y también se despliegan en el [repositorio de hitos](http://maven.springframework.org/milestone).
- **RELEASE**: Liberación generl, se produce similr a los anteriores, pero se despliega directamente al [repositorio de liberaciones de spring](http://maven.springframework.org/release) y al repositorio Maven Central.